# Windows equivalent of the Linux command 'touch'?

Tags: windows, file-attributes, touch

What do you use when you want to update the date-modified field of a file on Windows?

1. *commands* accessible via C++, .NET, C#, or something native to Windows (Vista preferably)
2. *tools/applications* preferably free, and if possible open source as well

Edit:
 there is already a page for applications as pointed out by CheapScotsman [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435/windows-version-of-the-unix-touch-command/51439).

If anyone knows how I can do this via C++, C#, [WSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) or something similar, well and good, else I would think everything else is covered in the linked question.

Comment: The four alternatives mentioned above, plus four more not mentioned here, can be found in the answer to a similar question: ["Windows Recursive Touch Command"](http://superuser.com/questions/251470/windows-recursive-touch-command/251507#251507 "Windows Recursive Touch Command")

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210201/how-to-create-empty-text-file-from-a-batch-file    mentions a load, including `REM.>a`

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/touch-for-windows works for me

Comment: I have tried all the solutions below. I have also tried using WSL but the simplest is echo '' > C:\path\filename - uses a default Windows CLI command and should be available on all Windows systems.

Answer (score 439, accepted):

If you want to touch the date stamp of a file using windows, use the following command at the command prompt:

```
copy /b filename.ext +,,
```

(where `filename.ext` is your file's name). The `+,,` is a special flag to `copy` telling it to simply [update the date/time on the file](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490886.aspx):

> * Changing the time and date of a file
>
> If you want to assign the current time and date to a file without modifying the file, use the following syntax:
>
> `copy /b Source+,,`
>
> The commas indicate the omission of the Destination parameter.

*Edit based on comments by Lumi and Justin:* put this in a batch file, eg. **touch.cmd**

```
@COPY /B %1+,, %1
```

This works even if the file is not in the current directory (tested on Windows 7).

Comment: This will be slow if the files are large.

Comment: `type touch.bat` is `@echo off` and next line `copy /b %1 +,,` - put it into `C:\bin` or what have you for your own scripts, and then you can use it like `touch myfile.txt`.

Comment: In Win7 this won't work if you are not in the folder containing the file. It will create a copy in the current working directory.

Comment: @Jamie yes, I also meet this problem.

Comment: @mob Note this was not slow on a large file.  I used it on a >1GB file on a network drive and it returned immediately (and worked).

Comment: @Jamie : Not related to Win7, applies to all OS. You need to be in the current directory as ,, will take the very same file with no path information (see technet link from josmh comment)

Comment: @Gish Domains: would you like to promote your answer as Community wiki. I think it is very helpful, although not marked as answer.

Comment: I created a [GIST](https://gist.github.com/tjbarbour/6356774) combining this answer with [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659647/how-to-get-folder-path-from-file-path-with-cmd) to automatically push/pop destination directory

Comment: @TJB batch files might consider starting with `@echo OFF`

Comment: If you need to do this in a remote folder (UNC path) - you must specify the destination to the copy command as well - `copy /b Source+,, Source` - where `Source` includes the full path to the file

Comment: `+,,`: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/07/10/10432879.aspx

Comment: `This will be slow if the files are large.` Actually, it is not slow, it does it in less than one second, and does not even light up the HD-access LED. Clearly the `copy` command in Windows has the `touch` command specially coded in, per the Technet article. +1 Great find; I never knew this one.

Comment: One small tiny little problem: it does copy all the files; it places them into CWD.

Comment: Windows XP doesn't like copying the file over itself from outside CWD. For this, use `pushd "%~dp1%"` before the CWD "touch", and `popd` afterward. (In case you're stuck supporting one of the millions of remaining XP machines...)

Comment: This did not work for me at all unless I added additional code to CD to the dir and CD back. Without that, even the copy that is created in the local directory still had the original timestamp despite the +,, flags. I used the powershell 1-liner instead and it worked perfectly

Comment: This is not an adequate replacement for the `touch` command, as it doesn't create the file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: this is not as useful - the most important feature, copying the timestamps from file1 to file2 with `touch file2 -r file1`, isn't handled.

Comment: Know this is a very old thread but easiest way now with a PowerShell is `New-Item`'s Alias: `ni <filename>`

Comment: thanks. Clearly a hack by MS, poor quality and poorly documented since "help copy" does not mention it

Comment: why is the /b parameter needed?

Comment: @Youda008 - `/b` tells `copy` that the file is binary rather than text. Also, [as noted by Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130710-00/?p=3843), the trailing `,,` at the end of the command is superfluous.

Comment: Doesn’t work on folders. Instead applies to the contents of the folder.

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work for me when called multiple times from within a batch file. In other words, if you've entered that command "@COPY /B %1+,, %1" (without quotes) into a file called touch.cmd and saved it to your System32 folder, if you then use "touch" in some batch file, it only works on the first call. Even if you cd to the same directory after each call of "touch", it only works on the first file you use it on. The second time you use it, that file doesn't get touched.

Comment: The `copy \\?\...` variant does not support long paths, when `type nul >> \\?\...` does, but only for a new file.

Answer (score 168):

I've used and recommend [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) which are native Win32 ports of lots of common Unix utilities. There is a `touch` command in there.

Comment: As almost every unix-to-windows port ever, this fails to work with unicode characters in the filenames outside of the encoding set as the default for non-unicode programs. Test filename that will trip up every such tool: `"test тест τεστ.txt"`

Comment: gnuwin32 has it.   but indeed, gnuwin32's also fails for unicode characters.

Comment: Update from 2017 In Windows 10 we can use the Linux subsystem for windows, which installs bash. No need for cygwin, MinGW, unxutils or any other partial unix to windows ports. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: @Davos have you tried that on any file other than your (usually unprivileged) user context? Because technically the userland side of LXSS is running as unprivileged user.

Comment: @0xC0000022L not sure what you mean in the context of the `touch` command. It's like anything else in nix environments, you can either do it or you can sudo it, or you can't because you don't have privileges.

Comment: @Davos _**user** context_! Start whatever WSL flavor you have installed. Now I am _assuming_ you have drive C: and it's NTFS (because the `%SystemDrive%` has to be). Inside your WSL shell prompt, execute the following: `touch /mnt/c/Windows/System32` (of course feel free to try that as well with other commands and go right ahead and try it with `sudo`/`su`, too). Everything in WSL (v1) is running as your NT user and has the same privileges, no matter if you use `sudo` or `su` within WSL. It's a sandboxed environment, comparable to unprivileged LXD/LXC containers. Very limiting. You see now?

Comment: These days it's literally easier to install the code-signed package [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) and use the `touch` from there, as in any case you can use it in any (NT) user context, whereas your suggestion limits you entirely to files and folders owned by the user starting the WSP app (or at least those only accessible with the appropriate ACEs set to modify timestamps). The above port should also work for the same reason. Your method with WSL will only work inside the constraints of the WSL sandbox ...

Comment: Sure do that then, the MingGW that comes with git for windows is certainly a decent option. It's arguable that the WSL v1 is doing it _right_ though, I mean what are you doing creating files in `System32` for? The windows OS is supposed to be privileged kernel space and the ability to clobber it with normal user privileges is a bizarre design decision. There are some fundamental differences between FS permissions on linux vs windows which exposes the fact that it's the norm for win users to run as default admins. A clear impedance in reconciling, for example, docker file mounts or in the WSL

Comment: "Very limiting", depends on what you're up to doesn't it.

Answer (score 111):

If all you want is to change the file's last modified date (which was my case):

```
C:\> powershell  (ls your-file-name-here).LastWriteTime = Get-Date
```

Comment: PowerShell FTW. I mean, seriously, unix is cool but PS is cooler.

Comment: You can update the last time write for multiple files / folders as well

Comment: This will work only on one file. For multiple files: ls * | ForEach-Object {$_.LastWriteTime = Get-Date}

Comment: If you want to do it recursively, this works pretty well: gci -recu -inc "*.*" | % { $_.LastWriteTime = Get-Date }

Comment: Not sure why, but the asterisks aren't showing up in my above comment -- the "." should be double-quote, asterisk, dot, asterisk, double-quote (you know, "star-dot-star".)  Anyway, tried to lookup the help to figure out why, but now it's not editable.  Darn.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83: use backticks ` for code: `gci -recu -inc "*.*" | % { $_.LastWriteTime = Get-Date }`

Comment: `touch` sets the time to a specific one or "now" if none is given. `.LastWriteTime` is the same, so you can do something like `.LastWriteTime = '12/30/99 23:59'`.

@matt: most likely, you're not very familiar with the *nix shell; PS still seems to have a long way to go --e.g., `sed`? `grep`? `vi`? :p

EDIT: Why are my Shift+Enter ignored? How to add new lines?

Comment: Unix touch is great for it's simplicity.

Comment: This worked perfectly. From a batch file, I could use a one-liner if I just surrounded the powershell command with double-quotes: ```powershell  "(ls your-file-name-here).LastWriteTime = Get-Date"``` or alternatively to set the date to another file's: ```powershell  "(ls your-file-name-here).LastWriteTime = (ls the-other-file-name-here).LastWriteTime"```

Comment: Doesn’t work on folders: `The property 'LastWriteTime' cannot be found on this object.`

Answer (score 69):

```
type nul >>file & copy file +,,
```

- Creates `file` if it does not exist.
- Leaves file contents alone.
- Just uses `cmd` built-ins.
- Both *last-access* and *creation* times updated.

**UPDATE**

Gah! This doesn't work on read-only files, whereas `touch` does. I suggest:

```
:touch
if not exist "%~1" type nul >>"%~1"& goto :eof
set _ATTRIBUTES=%~a1
if "%~a1"=="%_ATTRIBUTES:r=%" (copy "%~1"+,,) else attrib -r "%~1" & copy "%~1"+,, & attrib +r "%~1"
```

Comment: It's a pity that copy cannot ignore the +r attribute the way xcopy does. Or, it's a pity that xcopy doesn't support the weird `filename +,,` syntax.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work (at least not in Windows 7). It seems that the command interpreter does not update the timestamp of the destination of a redirection if the file is not actually modified (i.e., there is not data to redirect).

Comment: The `type nul ...` has an issue with the creation file time on NTFS (Windows 8.1): if the file were erased before, then it sets the erased file time, instead of a new file time.

Comment: The `copy \\?\...` variant does not support long paths, when `type nul >> \\?\...` does, but only for a new file.

Answer (score 33):

@dash-tom-bang:

Here is Technet's explanation of the mysterious '+' and commas:

> ```
> copy /b Source+,,
> ```
>
> The commas indicate the omission of
> the Destination parameter.

The copy command supports merging multiple files into a single destination file. Since a blank destination cannot be specified using a space character at the command prompt, two commas can be used to denote that.

And this is Technet's copy command reference: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490886.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490886(v=technet.10))

Comment: Now that's just messed up syntax. Seriously, *what were they thinking?* Also note the same documentation says "Destination: Required."... I'm amazed.

Comment: This doesn't seem to even work in Vista...  I wonder if they came to their senses?

Comment: Works in Windows 7

Comment: It worked for me even without commas:

copy file.ext+ 

So the documentation is as far from actual behaviour as the behaviour is from any reasonable expectations.

Comment: It worked in Windows Server 2008 but only if you are in the folder containing the file

Comment: So:

`copy foo.txt+bar.txt qux.txt` concatenates the two files and writes the result to the third file; `copy foo.txt+bar.txt` - if the destination file is omitted, it writes the result to the first file in the list; `copy foo.txt+,,` - concatenate file with "nothing" (just sets the last modification time), `copy foo.txt` wouldn't work; `/b` parameter means to treat the file as a binary file.

I have also verified that running the command on a very large file returns immediately.

Answer (score 23):

If you feel like coding it yourself, .NET offers the [`File.SetLastAccessTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setlastaccesstime.aspx), [`File.SetCreationTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setcreationtime.aspx) and [`File.SetLastWriteTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setlastwritetime.aspx) methods.

Answer (score 21):

here is a recursive version using powershell... this will change the last modified time for all files and subdirectories, and files within this directory's subdirectories

```
ps c:myDir> Get-ChildItem . * -recurse | ForEach-Object{$_.LastWriteTime = get-date}
```

Comment: Less verbose but yet using only standard Powershell shorthands: `ls * -recurse | % { $_.LastWriteTime = Get-Date }`

Answer (score 20):

I tried this to create an empty file in my batch script. You can use this:

```
ECHO text>file1.txt
```

Comment: This is BY FAR the best quick method.. I just needed to create a .gitignore file, and Windows 7 keeps complaining "must enter a filename" etc etc.  `echo pie>.gitignore` worked a treat - thanks!

Comment: @Alex This is unrelated, but that windows error is because the file starts with a period. There's a strange hack to get around that in Windows Explorer: make the file end with a period too. So type `.gitignore.` and when you press enter Windows removes the trailing period. Crazy, but it works.

Comment: I wish that I could give this enough upvotes that it would catch the big players in popularity.

Comment: This doesn't create an empty file though, file1.txt has "text" in it.

Comment: `touch` is not only used for creating empty files, and creating empty files is not the usage that the OP is asking about.   The question says "What do you use when you want to update the date-modified field of a file?"    This answer does not answer that question. Instead, the question this answer answers is: "how do you create a file containing arbitrary text, wiping out existing content if a file of the same name already exists?"   That's very much a misleading and possibly dangerous answer to the original question.

Answer (score 16):

The [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) project has Windows ports of the Gnu versions of the Unix command line utilities.

It comes as a number of separate packages and you can install just the commands you need with no other dependencies.  For `touch` you would need the [CoreUtils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) package.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a simple regfile I wrote to [add right-click "touch" in Windows explorer](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2004/02/20/76866.aspx). It'd be easy to script it, too, since it just calls:

```
cmd.exe /c copy %1+nul %1 /by
```

Comment: And don't forget `copy nul some_file` to create an empty file (which is what I see `touch` most often used for).

Comment: Ack!  Zip file inaccessible (something about brinkster22.com needing to be the referring site).  Jon, can you update this?

Comment: Works on Win7.   Does not work on WinXP: file time remains the same after executing "copy".

Answer (score 14):

[`cygwin`](http://www.cygwin.com/) comes with `touch`.  I know you mentioned that you don't want to install a whole framework, but cygwin is quite lightweight, and can be called from dos command window without the whole unix-like command line turned on.

You can also control what tools to install, so you could simply install the `touch.exe` file, and leave the rest of the framework.

Comment: To your point here, all you need to install is the touch.exe and cygwin.dll file in a directory to use the tool. There are no other dependancies relative to using cygwin based tools.

Comment: when I try this (win7x64) I need 4 cygwin dll's in addition to touch.exe: 
cygiconv-2.dll
cygintl-8.dll
cygwin1.dll
cyggcc_s-1.dll

Answer (score 13):

[Native win32 ports of many unix commands](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils), including touch.

I've used it before and it works well - no installation, no DLLs, etc

Answer (score 10):

Try this one from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/touch_win.aspx).

- No need to install.
- If you want, you can even modify the source.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 10):

This content can be saved to a reg file. This will add a right click context menu for all files with the "Touch File" ability (tested on Windows 7).
Copy **all** the following lines to reg file. Run the file and approve the question.
Right click on any file (or multiple files) - "Touch File" option is now available.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Touch File]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Touch File\command]
@="cmd /C copy /b \"%1\" +,,"
```

Comment: My preferred approach by far

Answer (score 9):

You could also install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) which gives you Touch as well as a plethora of other *NIX commands.

Comment: can't live on windows without cygwin.

Comment: And cygwin without mintty is pretty lame.

Comment: Today, I would recommend WSL in a mintty terminal.

Answer (score 5):

There are Windows ports of many Unix utilities.
Have a look at [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) or [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) projects.

Answer (score 5):

From a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435/windows-version-of-the-unix-touch-command) on Stack Overflow.

For updating timestamps (ignoring the other functionality of `touch`), I'd go with:

```
copy /b filename.ext +,,
```

Comment: This is a repeat of Gish Domains's answer from 2 yrs prior, without the explanation.

Answer (score 5):

in PowerShell try:

```
ni fileName.txt
```

`NI` is an alias of the [New-Item](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849795.aspx) cmdlet.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  Thanks for posting!  Can you add a link to a website that provides more information about the `ni` command, and perhaps describe more what the command does?

Comment: The `New-Item` cmdlet can't be used to update the time stamp of an existing file.

Comment: While it doesn't update timestamp, it does create a new file, which is what touch does. +1 from me.

Comment: I usually use touch to create files, but occasionally to update timestamps (to force a remake for example)

Answer (score 4):

How about codeproject "Touch for Windows": http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/touch_win.aspx

edit; Same question as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435/windows-version-of-the-unix-touch-command/51439

Comment: Thanks. I missed that in my search which resulted in loads of touch screen phone related stuff. Probably needs a better tag label I guess.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using git for one or more projects, the mingw based `git-bash` for Windows has the `touch` command.
I want to thank @greg-hewgill for pointing out to me that 'nix utilities exist for windows, because it was that which put me on the idea to try touch in git-bash.

Answer (score 4):

from the website:

> [Funduc Software Touch](http://www.funduc.com/fstouch.htm) is a free 'touch' utility that allows you
>   to change the time/date &/or attribute stamps on one or more files. In
>   addition, FS Touch can add/subtract a specified number of seconds from
>   the existing file time. You can specify which file(s) and/or
>   subdirectories to change via 'complex file masks'. The program can be
>   run from interactively or the command line. New to version 7.2 is a
>   command line switch to change file modified time stamp +/- the
>   specified number of seconds.
>
> FS Touch runs on Windows XP, Vista, Windows 7, & Windows 8.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted the 'touch' feature of cloning / duplicating the file dates from another file, natively, and be usable from a batch file.

So 'drag and drop' video file on to batch file, FFMPEG runs, then 'Date Created' and 'Date Modified' from the input file gets copied to the output file.

This seemed simple at first until you find batch files are terrible at handling unicode file names, in-line PowerShell messes up with file name symbols, and double escaping them is a nightmare.

My solution was make the 'touch' part a seperate PowerShell script which I called 'CLONE-FILE-DATE.ps1' and it contains:

```
param
(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$SourcePath,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$TargetPath
)

(GI -LiteralPath $TargetPath).CreationTime  = (GI -LiteralPath $SourcePath).CreationTime
(GI -LiteralPath $TargetPath).LastWriteTime = (GI -LiteralPath $SourcePath).LastWriteTime
```

Then here is example usage within my 'CONVERT.BAT' batch file:

```
%~dp0\ffmpeg -i "%~1" ACTION "%~1-output.mp4"

CHCP 65001 > nul && PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "%~dp0\CLONE-FILE-DATE.PS1" "%~1" "%~1-output.mp4"
```

I think the PowerShell is readable, so will just explain the batch speak:

**%~dp0** is the current directory of the batch file.

**%~1** is the path of the file dropped onto the batch without quotes.

**CHCP 65001 > nul** sets characters to UTF-8 and swallows the output.

**-ExecutionPolicy ByPass** allows you to run PowerShell without needing to modify the global policy, which is there to prevent people accidentally running scripts.

Answer (score 2):

I found a quick way to do it if you have vim installed (not great for big files, will open entire file then close it...)

```
vim foobar.txt +wq!
```

The "+" sets argument to run the following commands. "wq!" is "write, quit, force". This will open file, do a save, then close it immediately afterward.

Comment: Pointlessly complex, bulky and non-portable. -1

Comment: @MDXF As is many windows command line workflows.

Answer (score 2):

Save the following as touch.bat in your %windir%\system32 folder or add the 
folder in which it is saved to your PATH environment variable:

```
@echo off
if %1.==. goto end
if not exist %1 goto end
copy /b %1 +,, > nul
echo %1 touched!
:end
```

Sample usage:

```
touch *.cpp
touch somefile.c
```

Reference: [Microsoft KB 69581](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/69581)

Comment: Excellent! No external stuff, just copy. And of course most of us need it as a batch stript:)

Answer (score 2):

In powershell:

```
New-Item .\file.txt -ItemType File
```

I prefer to write `touch file.txt` like in linux, so I define this in my powershell profile

```
function New-File($filename)
{
   New-Item -ItemType File ".\$filename"
}

Set-Alias -Name touch -Value New-File
```

Note: you can edit your profile by running this command

```
notepad $PROFILE
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

fsutil file createnew new.txt 0

Comment: `The FSUTIL utility requires that you have administrative privileges.` -- and it doesn't behave like `touch` for existing files.

Answer (score 1):

The five alternatives mentioned above, plus three more not mentioned here, can be found on SuperUser: ["Windows Recursive Touch Command"](https://superuser.com/questions/251470/windows-recursive-touch-command/251507#251507)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly unrelated to the original question, but I find this very useful on Windows due to the GUI.

I'm using the TouchPro utility which provides a **GUI** (builds into explorer shell):

http://www.jddesign.co.uk/products/touchpro/touchpro.htm

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate this is an old question, I just discovered touch on my Windows 10 system. I downloaded and installed Git from [here](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) (I think) and it looks like touch and various other utilities are in the bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you *really* want to have the `touch` command available, you can put this in a batch file called `touch.bat` and stick it in `C:\Windows`:

```
TYPE NUL >>%1
```

Simple enough.

Comment: This method does NOT update the Modified Time on the following platforms: Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2016, Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

The Unix people fixed the general problem of updating the file date of any file with the *touch* command. However, for Windows, sometimes a simpler method is possible for special cases.

I need to update the timestamp of an application shortcut in Windows 8.1 in order to make changes to the background color of the Application Tile visible, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23528588/1845672). Rather than implementing one of the clever tools above, I find it easier to edit the comment field of the shortcut. Most people leave this empty, but of course, a useful comment is quickly conceived. And if a comment exists, adding or removing a final period does never harm.

Answer (score 0):

Because I needed this also and a number of other things, I've created my own shell extension that does this: [AllSorts](http://yoy.be/allsorts.html) I've also open-sourced this [here](https://github.com/stijnsanders/tools/tree/master/AllSorts)