# Changing file time stamps on Windows, simple way

Tags: windows-xp

I've seen a suggestion to change a file's modification timestamp with the copy command:

```
>copy file.ext +b
```

Is there a way to do this on a XP machine without copying or external programs?

**Edit:** I asked the question because my mp3 player irritatingly lists files by modification stamp. This is what I ended up doing:

```
>dir *.mp3 /b > dir.txt
>for /f "delims=" %f in (dir.txt) do copy "%f" +b
>del dir.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, `copy` seems to be the only way to go without using other external programs. See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/10426/windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch) question.