# How to modify timestamp in a dll or exe?

Tags: windows, dll, timestamp

Is there any tool to modify timestamp in a dll or exe?

Comment: What do you want to modify about it?

Comment: I want to modify the creation timestamp of an exe.

Comment: To make a batch file that does this with nothing to install, see about **touch.cmd** at the bottom of [Windows equivalent of the Linux command 'touch'?](http://superuser.com/a/764721/139292)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 utilities to do this are listed here:

http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-change-the-last-modified-date-creation-date-and-last-accessed-date-for-files-and-folders/

> [FileDate Changer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/filedatech.html)
>
> This program works on Windows 95, 98,
> ME, NT, 2000, and XP. I’m not really
> sure if it’s going to work on Vista or
> not. I’ll see if I can find one that
> does! Anyway, it works without any
> installation and only needs Internet
> Explorer version 3 or above installed
> on the computer. Click **Add Files**,
> select the dates you want changed and
> click **Change File Dates**! Pretty
> simple. **Note: Only works on files.**
>
> [SetFileDate 2.0](http://no-nonsense-software.com/freeware/)
>
> This program has a prettier interface
> and allows you to multi-select from an
> explorer type interface rather than
> having to add files one by one. You
> can also change the dates of folders
> using SetFileDate. It’s very small and
> very easy to use!
>
> [eXpress Timestamp Toucher](http://www.tucows.com/preview/506216/EXpress-TimeStamp-Toucher)
>
> The difference between this program
> and the others is that eXpress TT
> allows you to change the date and time
> for a file or folders AND optionally
> all sub-folders. This can prove to be
> very useful if you need to change the
> date and time for all files and
> folders under a specific folder. You
> can change the creation time, modified
> time, and last access time.

Comment: Is there any tool to change signature timestamp?

Comment: @Alien01: The **file** timestamp can be changed easily, for any file. But the **signature** timestamp is part of the signature - so no. (Unless you steal the signing key.)

Comment: @Alien01 - You would need to resign it to change that