# How can I change the timestamp on a file?

Tags: windows, timestamp, sysinternals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to modify timestamp in a dll or exe?](https://superuser.com/questions/135901/how-to-modify-timestamp-in-a-dll-or-exe)
>   [Windows equivalent of the Linux command 'touch'?](https://superuser.com/questions/10426/windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch)

How can I set the timestamp for a file via the command-line to a specific date?

My specific situation is Windows 7.

Comment: You should probably clarify your question and state that you want to choose the new timestamp. The two current answers assume you are looking for a Windows port of the Unix command `touch` that sets a files's timestamp to the current time.

Comment: I've looked through Sysinternals, and I'm pretty sure they don't have a utility for this. You should try the programs linked to from http://superuser.com/questions/135901/how-to-modify-timestamp-in-a-dll-or-exe

Comment: @William Jackson Changed, thanks for that. Also, if it truly was a port of the Unix command `touch`, I could specify the date. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_(Unix). Something is wrong with the auto linking though, make sure you get both parentheses.

Comment: I ... can't believe I never bothered to read `man touch`. You have taught me something new.

Comment: Duplicate of [Windows equivalent of the Linux command 'touch'?](http://superuser.com/questions/10426/windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch)

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Due to [William Jackson's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/292630/how-can-i-change-the-timestamp-on-a-file/292663#292663), I found a [similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582553/how-do-i-programatically-change-the-create-modify-access-date-on-a-file).

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582553/how-do-i-programatically-change-the-create-modify-access-date-on-a-file/582638#582638) states to use Powershell and these commands:

```
$(Get-Item ).creationtime=$(Get-Date "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm am/pm")
$(Get-Item ).lastaccesstime=$(Get-Date "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm am/pm")
$(Get-Item ).lastwritetime=$(Get-Date "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm am/pm")
```

**Edit**

Two examples:

(This one is from the comments:) Set the last-access time for a file `aaa.csv` to the current time:

```
$(Get-Item aaa.csv).lastwritetime=$(Get-Date)
```

Set the creation time of a file `foo.txt` to November 24, 2015, at 6:00am:

```
$(Get-Item foo.txt).creationtime=$(Get-Date "11/24/2015 06:00 am")
```

Comment: A slight variation that is recursive and a little shorter, though less readable: "gci -rec | %{ $_.lastWriteTime = ($_.lastAccessTime = ($_.creationTime = (get-date "2011-09-14T07:10:00"))) }"

Comment: For people that don't know much about Powershell, you have to put the filename after Get-Item. You can also omit the string after Get-Date to set the attribute to the current date/time like the default behavior of the touch command. Finally you can pass that code as an argument to the powershell command to have it just execute that from an existing batch file. Example: `powershell $(Get-Item aaa.csv).lastwritetime=$(Get-Date)`

Comment: What if I want to do this for every file in a directory?

Comment: Search for "Powershell every file". You might find questions like these: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16804265/756329 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/181036/756329

Comment: The date and time format is not as per the command, but the system wide one (so, in my system, it was dd/mm/yyy).

Comment: For every file in directory : `Get-ChildItem -File | foreach { $_.CreationTime=$(Get-Date) }`

Comment: How do you set creation time of one file to creation time of another file? How do you do it in a batch?

Answer (score 54):

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435/windows-version-of-the-unix-touch-command).

Specifically, this can be done natively with:

```
copy /b filename.ext +,,
```

This will set the timestamp to the current time.

[Documentation for the `copy` command is on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490886.aspx).

> The commas indicate the omission of the *Destination* parameter.

Comment: Can you explain how that is working? What is the `+,,`? How do I know what date it is being set to?

Comment: @josmh Check the documentation link for details. The timestamp gets set to the current time when you run the command. Are you implying that you want to be able to change the timestamp to an arbritary time of your choosing?

Comment: I'm not seeing how that helps me choose a new date for the file?

Comment: Main problem with this is when the file is not in current directory... it will copy the file to current directory instead of "touching" it in place.

Comment: @KaseySpeakman - this command relies on being in the current directory. Use `pushd FILEDIR`, before the comand and `popd` after

Comment: @JosephHansen This works by copying the file over itself, resulting in the file counting as having been modified "now"

Comment: FYI, "optimizations" in Vista+ means that, depending on context, the timestamp may not get updated as expected. It appears to work fine if this is the only command you run, but if your script does more, the timestamp may be left untouched.

Comment: Exactly what I needed for a quick file change.  In my case, had new files to add, wanted to use originals as template.  Copied modified files to another folder, added and overwrote to the current folder, then used this command to update all the dates on the file copies I had saved out.  Now I'll know which I edited and which I hadn't.

Answer (score 26):

[Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) to the rescue: try the freeware tool [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html).  It's a bunch of useful tools in one small command line program.  One of the commands allows you to specify either or both of **created time** and **modified time**, like this:

> nircmd.exe setfiletime "c:\temp\myfile.txt" "24-06-2003 17:57:11" "22-11-2005 10:21:56"

Comment: Also if you want to transfer time from a file to another, clonefiletime filefrom fileto works best!

Comment: Non-commandline, but more convenient for bulk editing: [BulkFileChanger](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bulk_file_changer.html) by Nirsoft

Answer (score 22):

Using Cygwin, to set the timestamp of test.txt to January 31, 2000, at 00:01.00:

```
touch -t 200001310001.00 test.txt
```

Comment: This comes back with invalid date format error.

Comment: @ziggy make sure you get all the zeros...

Comment: This worked perfectly for me `touch -t 201608221400 filename` to set it to 22.08.2016 14:00:00.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the following webpage: http://www.stevemiller.net/apps/

The Win32 Console Toolbox contains a utility called 'touch' that lets you modify the times on one or more files. I believe it only works with US format times, though.