# Windows batch command to assign specific time/date stamp to files

Tags: windows, batch, timestamp, file-attributes

I know how to assign the *current* time and date to a file using `copy /b filename.ext +,,` but how can I assign it a *different* time and date, as in this variable:  `set DateTime=01/01/1970 03:00 AM`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done natively in Windows CMD.

You can use NirSoft's **NirCmd** (free downlaod on his site http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) with a command like:

```
nircmd.exe setfiletime "c:\temp\myfile.txt" "24-11-2015 17:57:11" "22-11-2005 10:21:56"
```

---

Another option is to do it in PowerShell as seen in the answer "[How can I change the timestamp on a file?](https://superuser.com/a/292688/368970)", with commands like:

```
$(Get-Item c:\temp\myfile.txt).creationtime=$(Get-Date "11/24/2015 5:57 PM")
```