# Filezilla Directory Comparison showing directories green on local directory even when they are not updated

Tags: apache-http-server, svn, filezilla, tortoise-svn

I am using Filezilla v3.41.2 (Windows) with "Directory Comparison" mode. For my project files, Filezilla shows the green color correctly when there is a change in any file(s) but for directories, it showing green to some (not all) local directories which aren't changed. When I check inside the directories there are no new files/changes rather, it is showing different last modified time for the directories and sub-directories in comparison to the local folder. I hope due to the difference in last modified time it is showing me the green color.

I didn't change the folder name or any other attribute, then how come it shows the folder modified? Any help?

See this screenshot for reference:
[actual-problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZb05.png)

Further, the project folder is an SVN working folder which might change the folder or its attribute like icon (Green check mark or red) hence resulting in this unexpected behaviour.

I want Filezilla to show only those folders green which contains a new/modified file(s) and ignore the folders or its attribute entirely or any similar solution to prevent Filezilla misinform me about the changes in a directory.

Comment: So isn't your actual question *"Why a local directory modification time has changed, when its contents has not?"* - What has nothing to do with FileZilla.

Comment: Actually, I don't know what's causing this behaviour. So, I asked in the context of "Filezilla" in the hope that other people might have encountered it often while using it otherwise, usually, nobody notices a directory modified time in general use.

Comment: So did you test what FileZilla does, when you reset the modification time to that of the remote directory?

Comment: No. I don't know how to reset the modification time of a directory in windows. Can you tell me?

Comment: See [How can I change the timestamp on a file?](https://superuser.com/q/292630/213663)

Comment: Yes, Filezilla shows color green when I modify the folder attributes like icon. I want the system to ignore the changes made to a folder like an icon but it should show it green only when any file(s) is changed inside.

Comment: Now I see the problem: When SVN is updating the folder's icon to green check or just a folder icon, the system detects it as a change and thereby leaving Filezilla to show the folder as green (modified).

In fact, the case is I have files in the folder and I changed only 1 file inside it and in Filezilla, I have uploaded the modified file to the server as well but it still shows the folder green since it has a modification in the icon. So, in that case, I am supposed to upload the folder as well and that will lead to upload of all files again including the folder.

Any help? @MartinPrikryl

Comment: I do not know details of how SVN stores a folder status. But in any case, there's nothing like a folder icon. That's a virtual thing rendered by SVN shell extension. The actual status of the folder must be stored somewhere. Possibly there's a hidden file or something. Though even modifying the hidden file, should not update the folder timestamp. Maybe SVN updates the timestamp itself. Imo, the primary problem is that FileZilla compares folder timestamps. It's imo a bug.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I suspect the same. Then how to verify this?
Should I post it in FileZilla Forums? Since here I am not getting enough responses to solve the issue.

Comment: Actually, I do not see why you haven't posted this on FileZilla forum in the first place.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl just because I wasn't sure that it is a FileZilla related issue or some general system or SVN issue. Even if you read your first comment in this post, you too pointed out that it has nothing to do with FileZilla. But later, I realized it and now going to post. I must say you been very helpful and shared some thought provoking info. Thanks!