# PowerShell touch all files newer than

Tags: powershell, date, recursive, powershell-2.0, touch

I have found the following question on ServerFault:

[Windows recursive touch command](https://superuser.com/questions/251470/windows-recursive-touch-command/251507#251507)

Which partially answers my question with this answer:

[Windows recursive touch command](https://superuser.com/questions/251470/windows-recursive-touch-command/251507#comment-259712)

However, I would like to touch all files (in root and sub folders (recursively)) that are newer than 31st January 2013 (31/01/13). How would I go about doing this?

I have PowerShell 2 available.

**UPDATE:**

I have found that this scriptlet gets all of the files that I am after:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\path\to\files -recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge [DateTime] "1/31/2013 9:00AM" }
```

But I am not sure how to combine it with the "touch" command:

```
(ls file).LastWriteTime = DateTime.now
```

The following seems logical but I cannot test it as backing up my files will screw up my files' modified date/times:

```
(Get-ChildItem C:\path\to\files -recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge [DateTime] "1/31/2013 9:00AM" }).LastWriteTime = DateTime.now
```

So, will this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Powershell to use Unix touch seems silly to me.

Instead, just use native Powershell cmdlets.

[This article covers it:](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/06/01/use-powershell-to-modify-file-access-time-stamps.aspx)

Essentially:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $youFolder -Recurse | Foreach-Object {
    if ($_.LastWriteTime -ge [DateTime] "1/31/2013 9:00AM")
    { 
        $_.LastWriteTime = Get-Date
    }
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry but I think you have missed the point of my question. I want to filter for files that are newer than a given date, then change their timestamp to now. I have code for both but am not sure how to put them together. Thanks for the help so far though.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the checking. Added now. This does essentially what you ask but uses an If statement instead of the where-object

Comment: Brilliant! It works. I had to remove all of the new lines to run it from the command line but it worked.

Comment: Yes, I had it in a script form so to run it from the console it would have had to be moved to a one-line form.