# Tool to change file modified date with a tool which works inside File Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, software-rec

Looking for a tool to change a file's modified date which works from inside File Explorer context menu. I am aware of external tools like [BulkFileChanger](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bulk_file_changer.html) but I want to right click on a file and make the change.

Comment: since this question got closed, I reposted it on the software recommendation Stack Exchange website: [Change the file's modified date in Windows Explorer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/39163/903)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This one is freeware, and will change what you need plus various attributes that users don't normally have access to:

Attribute Changer
  http://www.petges.lu/

[image]

Comment: Can be found in your file's context menu after install.

Answer (score 11):

You can use
[File Date Touch](http://date.bghot.com) - Windows version of UNIX touch command

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com, Neil! Does 'File Date Touch' really work from within the context menu, or is it a separate utility? Also, does it have different functionality / benefits over the suggestion in the accepted answer?

Comment: @einpoklum I can answer that - yes it does have benefits - it DOESN'T show in context menu :) which I find great. Google has redirected me to this question, but on the other hand, I was looking for precisely this answer! Thanks Neil.

Answer (score 11):

I know its probably too late to answer this, but apparently this http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/SKTimeStamp.html does exactly what OP wanted:

> SKTimeStamp is a very simple shell extension which adds a new tab to the Explorer properties dialog. On that new tab, you can change the file/folder date and time.

Available for x86 and x64 Windows systems.

Answer (score 9):

You can change the create date from the command line. You must first change the system clock date, then open a command prompt window at the current working directory, and issue the command:

```
copy /b [filename] + ,,
```

This uses the concatenation directive with the binary (/b) switch, basically copying the file to itself and incidentally setting the create date of the "new" file to the current system clock.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which explicitly insists on an answer that works inside File Explorer.

Comment: I was just looking for a way to change the mtime on a file and this method worked great for me.

Comment: This does not answer the question, but the OP might find it useful -- there are lots of reasons why a question might not be phrased in exactly the way that leads to useful information -- and others, like me, looking for answers, might also find it useful.

Comment: For some reason this didn't quite work for me, but doing 
copy /b [filename] [new_filename] 
did. Also I had to use cmd instead of powershell. Thanks

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/764733/89165) adds the above command to the File Explorer Right Click Context Menu.