# How can I copy/duplicate timestamp from a file and apply it to the directory where the file is located in Windows?

Tags: windows

I accidentally applied/copied wrong timestamps on a list of directories, and I would now like to copy timestamps from a file in the folder and apply it to the directory, e.g.: `c:\myfiles\backup\file.txt`

I need to apply "date modified" attribute/info from `file.txt` to `c:\myfiles\backup` and `c:\myfiles`

Answer (score 0):

You could check the [solution offered here](https://superuser.com/questions/268082/tool-to-change-file-modified-date-with-a-tool-which-works-inside-file-explorer) which uses a third party utility called [File Date Touch](http://date.bghot.com/file-date-touch.php) to do what you want to do.

Addition: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217829/change-modification-time-stamp-with-vbscript) you can find a VBScript solution to the above problem. Shouldn't be too difficult to modify the script to accept and read a file containing the file/folder name.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thank you! Looks very nifty but requires me to manually extract the attributes and populate. Hoping for a way to duplicate attributes from the file to folder - if it can be scripted that would really make my day!

Comment: How about this, then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217829/change-modification-time-stamp-with-vbscript