# The Command "copy /b Source+,," does not work in a Batch Script

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I'd like to update the timestamp (Modified Date) of a file in a batch script by using the following command

```
"copy /b Source+,,"
```

but it does not work. I tried the same command through command line & it works fine.
I've even tried to run the batch script as an administrator but that didn't solve it either

Any ideas ?

Comment: This works here in a bat file. What is the file you are passing as parameter? Is it open in any process?

Comment: Please read [this](http://superuser.com/a/764721) answer.

Comment: Hi @DavidPostill I found this command from the answer to the question you've mentioned though I faced this issue in a batch script.

Comment: Read **all** the comments to the linked answer ...

Comment: have you simply tried it without the 2 commas. They are not needed, and from the linked answer (thanks, @DavidPostill ), they had to create a test within cmd.exe to test for the presence of the commas