# How to manually change the Last Modified Date of a Windows file?

Tags: windows, filesystems, date, save-as, date-modified

Windows explorer shows files and their Last Modified date, based on when they were last saved. Is there a way to  manually edit that date in File Properties or through Command line, without naturally re-saving the file?

Comment: you could use [windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch](https://superuser.com/questions/10426/windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch) and precede it with `date <your date>` and then change the date back. not a nice solution but should work. or you could create a batch file (or powershell) which will take the date and filename as parameters and you save the current date as a variable, change the date to the date parameter, "touch" the filem, reset date from variable saved.

Comment: i don't understand the answer there since it doesn't give a concrete example, like changing a file's modified date to dec.31 2012

Comment: You could read this article [How to Change File Date or Timestamp in Window](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/change-accessed-modified-created-file-date-timestamp-windows/) Try the powershell commands.

Comment: I did not provide an answer, it was just a comment. and I would go with Seven's link, I always forget about the cool powershell stuff :)